# How to use DSL.coalesce with lists of fields?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, coalesce

Using Jooq, I am trying to fetch from a table by `id` first, if no matches found, then fetch by `handle` again.

And I want all fields of the returned rows, not just one.

```
        Field<?> firstMatch = DSL.select(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .from(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .where(Tables.MY_TABLE.ID.eq(id))
                .asfield(); // This is wrong, because it supports only one field, but above we selected Tables.MY_TABLE.fields(), which is plural. 

        Field<?> secondMatch = DSL.select(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .from(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .where(Tables.MY_TABLE.HANDLE.eq(handle))
                .asfield(); // Same as above.

dslContext.select(DSL.coalesce(firstMatch, secondMatch))
          .fetchInto(MyClass.class);
```

Due to the mistake mentioned above in the code, the following error occurs:

```
Can only use single-column ResultProviderQuery as a field
```

I am wondering how to make `firstMatch` and `secondMatch` two lists of fields, instead of two fields?

I tried

```
        Field<?>[] secondMatch = DSL.select(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .from(Tables.MY_TABLE.fields())
                .where(Tables.MY_TABLE.HANDLE.eq(handle))
                .fields();
```

but the following error occurred in the line containing `DSL.coalesce`

```
Type interface org.jooq.Field is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds much more like something you'd do with a simple `OR`?

```java
dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
          .where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(id))
          // The ne(id) part might not be required...
          .or(MY_TABLE.ID.ne(id).and(MY_TABLE.HANDLE.eq(handle))
          .fetchInto(MyClass.class);
```

If the two result sets should be completely exclusive, then you can do this:

```java
dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
          .where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(id))
          .or(MY_TABLE.HANDLE.eq(handle).and(notExists(
              selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(id))
          )))
          .fetchInto(MyClass.class);
```

If on your database product, a query using `OR` doesn't perform well, you can write an equivalent query with `UNION ALL`, which might perform better.

Comment: I see. Does that mean `DSL.coalesce()` doesn't support lists of `Field`s?

Comment: @powerseed: `COALESCE()` doesn't do what you think it's doing... It takes a variable number of arguments, and returns the first non-`NULL` value. It can't operate on tuples / rows...